# Validating Undefined in React Native

Tags: react-native

I have a situation where I'm trying to pass some params via `onPress` to another screen. However I'm unable to capture the Undefined state and it gives me the red screen error -

> Type Error: undefined is not an object.

Here's my snippet. Am I missing something?

```
const pressHandle = (item) => {
        const capVal = state.payload.find((grabVal) => grabVal.jobId === item.jobId).jobId;

        console.log(capVal); // in a defined case, I have a log so the query is correct.

        if( typeof(capVal) !== undefined || typeof(capVal) != null ) {
            setGrabber(capVal);
        } else {
            setGrabber('undefined!');
        }
        console.log(grabber);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to do a null check your error is probably appearing due to accessing a property of an undefined item when finding an item.

Adding ?.jobId will access the jobId only if an item is found and then you can check if(capVal) which will run if capVal has a value

```
const pressHandle = (item) => {
        const capVal = state.payload.find((grabVal) => grabVal.jobId === item.jobId)?.jobId;

        console.log(capVal); // in a defined case, I have a log so the query is correct.

        if(capVal) {
            setGrabber(capVal);
        } else {
            setGrabber('undefined!');
        }
        console.log(grabber);
}
```